# Add a second SSD to an existing rpool on a ZFS system

Tags: 22.04, zfs

I have just installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on a computer with TWO SSDs using the ZFS filesystem

How do I incorporate the second physical SSD into my rpool of my ZFS filesystem?

Comment: How is ZFS configured currently ? Are both SSDs same size ? Do you want to add SSD number two for more space or for extra redundancy / fault tolerance ?

Comment: One is 500GB; the other is 1 TB. No, maybe I'm not understanding ZFS correctly, but I wanted to include it so as to make the overall storage space 1.5 TB total. Am I using ZFS correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Those are my [personal notes](http://free_zed.gitlab.io/articles/2021/01/extend-zfs-root-pool-after-ubuntu-installation/en/) based on a [Focal Fossa (Ubuntu 20.04)](https://ubuntu.com/blog/zfs-focus-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-whats-new) providing only a mono-disk installation.

Here's how to enhance a mono-disk installation into a mirrored-disk installation to use data resilience provided by ZFS.

### Howto

- `sda` is the disk used by installer
- `sdb` is the disk we're going to add to create a mirror

```
user@focal:~$ lsblk -a
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0   513M  0 part
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part
├─sda5   8:5    0     2G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda6   8:6    0     2G  0 part
└─sda7   8:7    0   927G  0 part
sdb      8:16   0 931,5G  0 disk
```

```bash
user@focal:~$ blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="BFE4-2413" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="f0771fca-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="42456868-afc5-4dea-8b73-11257b84890e" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="f0771fca-05"
/dev/sda6: LABEL="bpool" UUID="11578277722432725130" UUID_SUB="9520999198366150859" TYPE="zfs_member" PARTUUID="f0771fca-06"
/dev/sda7: LABEL="rpool" UUID="13693210375688435814" UUID_SUB="8709443765040685487" TYPE="zfs_member" PARTUUID="f0771fca-07"
```

Ubuntu creates 2 [`pools`](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/zfs-term.html#zfs-term-pool) :

1. `bpool` : containing boot *pool*
2. `rpool` : containing root *pool*, with all file-system

```bash
user@focal:~$ zpool list
NAME    SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CKPOINT  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP    HEALTH  ALTROOT
bpool  1,88G  91,2M  1,79G        -         -     0%     4%  1.00x    ONLINE  -
rpool   920G  3,19G   917G        -         -     0%     0%  1.00x    ONLINE  -
```

```bash
user@focal:~$ zpool status
  pool: bpool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: none requested
config:

    NAME           STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    bpool          ONLINE       0     0     0
      f0771fca-06  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors

  pool: rpool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: none requested
config:

    NAME           STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    rpool          ONLINE       0     0     0
      f0771fca-07  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

Run `fdisk` to copy `sda` partition table to `sdb` using sfdisk compatible script files ([*see manpage*](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/fdisk.8.html#script%20files)).

```bash
user@focal:~$ fdisk /dev/sda #copy to file with O
user@focal:~$ fdisk /dev/sdb #import from file with I
```

```bash
user@focal:~$ lsblk -a
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0   513M  0 part
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part
├─sda5   8:5    0     2G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda6   8:6    0     2G  0 part
└─sda7   8:7    0   927G  0 part
sdb      8:16   0 931,5G  0 disk
├─sdb1   8:17   0   513M  0 part
├─sdb2   8:18   0     1K  0 part
├─sdb5   8:21   0     2G  0 part
├─sdb6   8:22   0     2G  0 part
└─sdb7   8:23   0   927G  0 part
```

[Attach](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/zfs-zpool.html#zfs-zpool-attach) the twin partitions on pools :

```bash
user@focal:~$ sudo zpool attach bpool f0771fca-06 /dev/sdb6
user@focal:~$ sudo zpool attach rpool f0771fca-07 /dev/sdb7
```

Tada!

```bash
user@focal:~$ zpool status
  pool: bpool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: resilvered 92,2M in 0 days 00:00:01 with 0 errors on Sun Jan  3 22:22:09 2021
config:

    NAME             STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    bpool            ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-0       ONLINE       0     0     0
        f0771fca-06  ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdb6         ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors

  pool: rpool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: resilvered 4,05G in 0 days 00:01:06 with 0 errors on Sun Jan  3 22:24:05 2021
remove: Removal of vdev 1 copied 3,36M in 0h0m, completed on Sun Jan  3 21:14:16 2021
    456 memory used for removed device mappings
config:

    NAME             STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    rpool            ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-0       ONLINE       0     0     0
        f0771fca-07  ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdb7         ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

### 30/4/2021 edit

1. Steps compatible with [version `21.04` «_Hirsute Hippo_»](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/hirsute-hippo-release-notes/19221) instaler;

   - the partition numbering seems to be continuous now
2. Enlarge `swap` with the available partition on the added disk

```bash
user@hirsute:~$ free -h
              total       utilisé      libre     partagé tamp/cache   disponible
Mem:           11Gi       974Mi        10Gi       7,0Mi       259Mi        10Gi
Swap:          2,0Gi      0B           2,0Gi

user@hirsute:~$ sudo mkswap /dev/sdb5
Configure l'espace d'échange (swap) en version 1, taille = 2 GiB (2147479552 octets)
pas d'étiquette, UUID=bbbbbbbb-bbbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbb

user@hirsute:~$ grep swap /etc/fstab
UUID=aaaaaaaa-aaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaa   none    swap    sw  0   0
UUID=bbbbbbbb-bbbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbb   none    swap    sw  0   0

user@hirsute:~$ sudo swapon -U bbbbbbbb-bbbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbb

user@hirsute:~$ free -h
              total       utilisé      libre     partagé tamp/cache   disponible
Mem:           11Gi       1,0Gi        10Gi       7,0Mi       261Mi        10Gi
Swap:          4,0Gi      0B           4,0Gi
```